# Userform events and calling private sub

Tags: excel, vba

I have userform with textboxes. Textbox restricts input of some character or rather allows input of numbers commas and dots. Code is within `key_press` event of textbox. Everything works fine as long as code below is in the `key_press` event. When I enter `call private sub` with same code from different sub it does not work.

Why it does not work?

Code within `Key_press` event:

```
Private Sub netto_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

Select Case KeyAscii

    Case Asc("0") To Asc("9")
    Case Asc("-")
    Case Else
    KeyAscii = 0

End Select

End Sub
```

Code with call sub within `Key_press` event:

```
Private Sub netto_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

Call klawisze

End Sub

Private Sub klawisze()

Select Case KeyAscii

    Case Asc("0") To Asc("9")
    Case Asc("-")
    Case Else
    KeyAscii = 0

End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: have you set a breakpoint and debugged it to see what it's doing?

Comment: Actually I executed it line by line using "step into" and well nothing really happend. Event called private sub, private sub executed as it should and nothing... still working wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where close to the right solution. You simply need to pass argument `KeyAscii` in your `klawisze` sub (which accept corresponding parametr: `ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger`):

```
Private Sub netto_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Call klawisze(KeyAscii)
End Sub

Private Sub klawisze(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case Asc("0") To Asc("9")
        Case Asc("-")
        Case Else
            KeyAscii = 0
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: By the way... is it possible to insert `if` value is passed for specified event `then` ?

Comment: not sure I understand what do you mean..can you clarify please?

Comment: I use this private sub for few textboxes to restrict input of characters. However some textboxes are less restrict then this code and allow user to add more characters. So is it possible create `if` value passed from specified event `less_restrict_textbox` `then`...

Comment: you can do something like this: `Call klawisze(KeyAscii,"netto")` in event hadler and declare sub as `Private Sub klawisze(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger, textboxName As String)` and then check in sub: `If textboxName="anyName you need" Then`